# How to turn speed of table visual

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I use table visual, I use measure (from measure table) and field (from table)
result is table visual use longtime to show data and sometime fail to load,
what should i do for turning performance in Power BI

Comment: You need DAX studio(External tool) to analyze your codes performance, and performance analyzer to test report performance. Get the habit of Using DAX Studio to test the performance of your codes. You can download and use it with no charge.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the Performance Analyzer ? you can check which part of the PBI takes more time, your connection ? your measure ? your power queries ? etc ?

[image: PA]